# How to create custom calendar in android kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-xml, nestedrecyclerview

I need create custom calendar. But when I create calendar during scroll lagged and slowed. I implement calendar use nested recyclerview
[image: I want to create calendar like this]

I did try create nestedrecycler view
parent recyclerview is LinearLayout Vertical childs (month) is GridLayout